# SharpDX: Move an object without manipulating the vertices

Tags: c#, 3d, directx, sharpdx

i am using SharpDX and trying to move an object in worldspace.
As i load an object from web (.obj-file) the received data gets written into a buffer. So i do not have a chance to manipulate it.
I know that one can move, rotate and scale object with the help of a matrix. But then again, i only got the vertex- and indexbuffer for the mesh. Is there anything i have overseen to transform a mesh in worldspace?

Comment: if thats only one object you have, you can manipulate camera instead of the model. move it forward and backward, rotate it around model... also change directional light source to make it more reliable.

Comment: I also have thought about that possibility. Currently i am trying exactly this. There is a worldviewprojection i am trying to multiply the transform of an object with it. Because there is always only one drawcall for an object, this should maybe work. But i am still not really sure about this approach. Thank you anyway!

Comment: It's exactly the "World" part of your WorldViewProjection transform that you are looking for. Just set an according matrix and let the vertex shader do the transformation. View represents the camera's orientation and position and Projection represents intrinsic camera parameters. The overall matrix is WorldViewProjection=World\*View\*Projection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know enough but I think you need to add a worldViewMatrix for each mesh later have a vector3 called position, a property for your each mesh to pass parameters trough Matrix.Translation(position.x,position.y,position.z). Your buffer is stored in gpu you can not change it directly so you move them with matrices.

Something like inside mesh class or whatever you use:

```
Matrix WorldViewMatrix;
public Vector3 Position;

    public void Render( SharpDX.Direct3D11.Buffer constantBuffer, SharpDX.Direct3D11.Device device, Matrix viewProj )
    {
    WorldViewMatrix =  Matrix.Scaling(Scale) * Matrix.RotationX(Rotation.X) * Matrix.RotationY(Rotation.Y) * Matrix.RotationZ(Rotation.Z) * Matrix.Translation(Position.X, Position.Y, Position.Z) * viewProj;
    WorldViewMatrix.Transpose();
    device.ImmediateContext.UpdateSubresource(ref WorldViewMatrix, constantBuffer);
    //device.ImmediateContext.PixelShader.SetShaderResource(0, textureView);
    device.ImmediateContext.Draw(VerticesCount,0);
    }
```

Later you will create viewMatrix

```
var viewProj = Matrix.Multiply(myMesh.ViewLayer.Camera.getView(), proj); 
//Whatever your organization is I did it like myMesh.ViewLayer.Camera.getView() for my purpose. I assume you had camera setup already.
```

Finally ready to move:

```
Matrix proj = Matrix.Identity;

    RenderLoop.Run(form, () =>{
            var viewProj = Matrix.Multiply(myMesh.ViewLayer.Camera.getView(), proj);
            //...
                if (IHandler.KeyRight) { myMesh.Position.X += 0.050f; }
                if (IHandler.KeyLeft)  { myMesh.Position.X -= 0.050f; }
                if (IHandler.KeyUp)    { myMesh.Position.Z += 0.050f; }
                if (IHandler.KeyDown)  { myMesh.Position.Z -= 0.050f; }
                if (IHandler.KeyQ)     { myMesh.Position.Y -= 0.050f; }
                if (IHandler.KeyE)     { myMesh.Position.Y += 0.050f; }
            //...
            myMesh.Render(contantBuffer, device, viewProj);
    });
```

My Result here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dn4RdD6tc7g